# How to get the row values selected by aggregate function which do not appear in group by function in joins?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a sql query which uses the aggregate function for left join, now I need to also fetch the column values from the notes tables which do not appear in the group by clause.

```
SELECT
  jobs.*,
  n.complete_date
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN
(
    select job_id, MAX(`timestamp`) AS complete_date
    from notes 
    where (type="complete" OR type IS NULL)
    group by job_id
) n
  ON (jobs.id=n.job_id)
WHERE (jobs.status="complete" OR jobs.status="closed")
ORDER BY complete_date ASC
```

Should I do self join here to get the notes row?

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Please tag only the one database that you are using.

Comment: If you don't aggregate them, then they are not available to the main query. Just add the aggregation function(s) and problem solved.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: here the aggregate function is selecting the job id with max(timestamp) , I want to select job id and alongside get the other columns present in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions instead of aggregation:

```
SELECT j.*, n.*
FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT job_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) AS complete_date
      FROM notes 
      WHERE n.type = 'complete' OR n.type IS NULL
     ) n
     ON j.id = n.job_id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE j.status = ('complete', 'closed')
ORDER BY complete_date ASC
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I am wondering is there a solution with group by, because of performance issue?

Comment: @KishyNivas . . . This should have better performance than an aggregation solution.